# How to get nearby ATMs from current location using Angular 7 code?

Tags: angular, geolocation, google-nearby

I want to display nearby ATM from current location using Angular 7. Please help to get the codes or demo.

Comment: Please share some research details that `you have found` or some code samples

Answer (score -1):

You can use this api

`https://apis-bank-dev.apigee.net/apis/v1/locations/atms`

Please create a angular service that make request to above api with required parameters mentioned in above site.

[Documentation](https://openbank.apigee.io/open-data/apis/get/atms)